# Removing an existing css position rule

Tags: css

Never had this problem before but it's come up today and I don't know how to deal with it.

I have an external script which loads it's own css rules (after the initial page styles are loaded).

One of the properties is setting a position for left :

```
.rule {
    left: 450px;
}
```

I need to over-ride this on my page, which I know I can do by setting a new value and adding !important :

```
.rule {
    left: 0!important;
}
```

But what I really need to do is change the rule, removing left completely :

```
.rule {
    right: 10%;
}
```

Using the above rules together....

```
.rule {
    left: 0!important;
    right: 10%
}
```

Won't work as left is now being set to position 0.

Is there anyway I can completely ***remove*** the existing left rule without access to the css file that is serving it?

Comment: Have you tried `left:auto`?

Comment: try left:auto or left:none to see it they work?

Comment: Literally just tried that and yes it works. Does it works across all browsers? I know left: unset; can be used but is not widely supported yet.

Comment: try with this .rule {  left: auto !important;  right: 10% !important; }

Comment: Ok so auto is the only safe way to do this right now?

Comment: yes @Grant and it should be important to over ride.

Comment: Yep I know about the importance of !important (there's a sentence I never thought I'd say - haha). Cheers all ;)

Comment: and also you can remove .rule and add new class where ever you need by using jQuery

Comment: Yes jQuery was going to be my next port of call if there wasn't a native css way to do it. Again thanks ;)